# howe to add firebase realtime data to my project veins ( in omnet ++ )

Tags: c++, firebase, omnet++, veins, sumo

How to establish the connection with Firebase in my Veins project? I have downloaded the Firebase C++ SDK and imported it into my Veins project. However, I'm not sure how to configure my project to enable adding and retrieving data from Firebase .

1. I have imported the Firebase SDK into my project.
2. i try this code :

```
include <veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/Internet.h>
#include "veins/firebase_cpp_sdk/include/firebase/app.h"
#include "veins/firebase_cpp_sdk/include/firebase/auth.h"
#include "veins/firebase_cpp_sdk/include/firebase/database.h"
void Internet::init(){

      firebase::AppOptions options;
       
        options.set_api_key("297209001490");
        options.set_database_url("https://my-app-veins-m2-rsd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
        firebase::App* app = firebase::App::Create(options);
        firebase::database::Database* database = firebase::database::Database::GetInstance(app);
      
}
```

3. But it displays this error :

> undefined reference to `firebase::App::Create(firebase::AppOptions const&)'
>
> undefined reference to `firebase::database::Database::GetInstance(firebase::App*, firebase::InitResult*)'

Comment: Have you read the documentation, specially on how to link with the libraries since it looks like a linker problem. The error states it cannot find an implementation (definition) of the functions you try to call.